# Find $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ from these equations in matrix form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

> Find $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2$ from these equations in matrix form
>   $$
> \left\{
> \begin{aligned} 
> \frac{a^{2}}{2^{2}-1^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{2^{2}-3^{2}}+\frac{c^{2}}{2^{2}-5^{2}}+\frac{d^{2}}{2^{2}-7^{2}}&=1 \\
> \frac{a^{2}}{4^{2}-1^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{4^{2}-3^{2}}+\frac{c^{2}}{4^{2}-5^{2}}+\frac{d^{2}}{4^{2}-7^{2}}&=1 \\
> \frac{a^{2}}{6^{2}-1^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{6^{2}-3^{2}}+\frac{c^{2}}{6^{2}-5^{2}}+\frac{d^{2}}{6^{2}-7^{2}}&=1 \\
> \frac{a^{2}}{8^{2}-1^{2}}+\frac{b^{2}}{8^{2}-3^{2}}+\frac{c^{2}}{8^{2}-5^{2}}+\frac{d^{2}}{8^{2}-7^{2}}&=1
> \end{aligned} 
> \right.
> $$

I'm not too sure if it could be solved in standard way like calculate the denominators one-by-one then make  $\begin{bmatrix} a^2 \\ b^2 \\ c^2 \\ d^2 \\ \end{bmatrix}$ matrix for solving linear equation system. I'm sure there's a "beautiful" way there. I'm thinking of using sigma notation (summation) combined with matrix, but have no idea to do it.

Is there a fashioned way to find the solution in matrix form?

Comment: Are you sure the $5^2-1^2$ isn't supposed to be $6^2-1^2$, and the $5^2-7^2$ to be $6^2-7^2$?

Comment: This is simple to set up in *Mathematica*, which gives the answer directly:  ${890497 \over 27193}$.

Comment: @Marconius Ah, typo. Thank you for reminding me.

Comment: My idea: firstly subtract  1 from both sides of each equation. Then the right sides will all be $0$. Now take aid of the determinant. I think it should be the simpler way.

Comment: @SubhadeepDey Do you mean using Cramer rule after subtracting 1 from both sides?

Comment: I am sorry, Cramer rule will be an easy process, but I think it will appear cumbersome and tedious . I tried to say that if $ax+by=0$ and $cx+dy=0$,  then $\begin{vmatrix} a& b\\ c&d\\ \end{vmatrix}$ $=0$. But now i am thinking thet it would help much.

Comment: There must be a reason all the denominators are differences of squares. Is this a contest question, or just a case of life imitating art?